# RMagick not maintained any more?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rmagick

At the RMagick repo on Github, a message was uploaded yesterday saying the main author cannot continue to maintain the project, and is looking for new people to take over. (I would certainly crash it were I to ever attempt such a job!). You can see their readme here: http://github.com/rmagick/rmagick.

In your opinion, where should a Rails 3 / Heroku / S3 app go, given that it is trying to use Paperclip for file uploads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about whether to use RMagick or another alternative such as ImageScience. Is that correct? You don't actually need any of those libraries: Paperclip doesn't require them as long as the ImageMagick binaries are available on the app servers.

Comment: Hi Eric... if that's correct then what role does RMagick play at all, if any?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the Paperclip source, none at all. Out of the box, Paperclip calls the ImageMagick binaries to do thumbnail processing, etc. If you wanted to use RMagick, ImageScience, etc., you would probably need to write your own processor (see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/processor.rb).